# What is Read ONLY Role to give to Oracle developers to veiw the Flashback Data via versions Query

Tags: oracle, flashback

I have created Oracle FDA and its tracking the DMLS on the tables but can i know if there is a specific role that could be granted to users to view the data using VERSIONS BETWEEN Query

GRANT FLASHBACK ANY TABLE or GRAN FLASHBACK on tblname seems to have access to flashack the table as well.
Is there a way for a user to just view the data using Query

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9012.htm#SQLRF01802) provides this information

> To flash back a table to an earlier SCN or timestamp, you must have either the FLASHBACK object privilege on the table or the FLASHBACK ANY TABLE system privilege. In addition, you must have the SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, and ALTER object privileges on the table.

So if you grant only SELECT and FLASHBACK on a table, the granted user is allowed to make a [flashback query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS613), but is *not allowed* to FLASHBACK the table.

The attempt of `FLASHBACK TABLE` will fail with

```
 ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```